# Prove that $G/H$ is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

Consider the set $G$ of real $2\times2$ matrices of the form $\left(\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\ 0&d\end{array}\right)$, where $a\ne0$, $d\ne0$. Then I have checked that $G$ is a group under matrix multiplication. Consider the set $H=\left\{\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&b\\ 0&1\end{array}\right)~:~b\in\Bbb{R}\right\}$. I have also checked $H\trianglelefteq G$.

Now how do I show $G/H$ is abelian.

I have tried showing the the map $g\mapsto g^{-1}$ is an isomorphism on this quotient but to no avail.

Comment: I think the condition for membership in $G$ should be $d\ne0$ where you have $b\ne0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson.. thanks. It was a typo. I have edited it.

Comment: Take the map that sends all entries to themselves except for $b$ which goes to $0$. Then $H$ will be the kernel and the quotient group will be the set of diagonal $2\times 2$ matrices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: define $\phi:G\to \mathbb{R}^{\times}\times\mathbb{R}^{\times}$ by 
$$ \phi\Big(\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&d\end{bmatrix}\Big)=(a,d)$$
and show that $\phi$ is a surjective group homomorphism with kernel $H$.

Comment: Wow, that was elegant!

Comment: Thanks. As a general rule, I find the first isomorphism theorem very helpful in understanding a quotient group.